# Give Events enough time to complete

Tags: java

I have written a simple minesweeper app and I'm having trouble when:

The user clicks a mine and after that I want to cycle through all the mines and 'explode' each mine, one at a time, with a half second delay between events.

The cycles are working fine but all of the mines 'explode' at the end of the cycles.

```
// a 9x9 GRID of buttons
for( row=0;row<maxrows;row++)// cycle though 9 rows
{
   for( col=0;col<maxcols;col++)// cycle through 9 cols
   {
       if(squares[row][col].EState == EState.Mine)// if the grid at row col is a mine
       {
           DisplayTile(row,col,TileType.Mine);// show the mine
           try
             {
                 MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.explosion02);// make an explosion sound
                 mp.start();
             } catch(Exception ex) {
                 System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
                 ex.printStackTrace();
             }
             //I would like the display and explosion to actually happen now before we get to the nect mine
           try
           {
              Thread.sleep(500);
           }
           catch(Exception ex)
           {
               Log.d("test",ex.getMessage());
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: That `MediaPlayer` is not the JavaFX media player. What library are you using?

Comment: Only with a Thread + Handlers OR with setting an animation to start at the end of another animation (with Animation API) this can be achieved, the reason is that your UI is only updated after the for loops ends

Comment: It's android.media.MediaPlayer from android API.

Comment: Had a similar issue with a thread being spawned to use a web API, had to wait for the API to return results.  Ended up making the main thread wait to continue by using a CountDownLatch

Comment: Friends, thanks for the answers. I believe that the animation reply from Marcos Vasconcelos is the answer that looks like the one that will bear the most fruit and I will pursue it further. Thanks again,